# Getting click event on element inside from popup in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

In my extension popup, click on button is not working. click listener is not attaching maybe. can anybody give me simple example how should i attach click listener on element inside popup.

regards & thanks.

Comment: Attaching a listener in popup can be done in the exact way as in a normal webpage. Post some code to see what might be the problem.

Comment: thanks, i have attach the listener where i have created popup content and its working. Thanks